# How to remove unwanted items from a printed list?

Tags: java, math

Write a Java function that accepts an integer, `n`, as input and outputs a string of integers from `1` to `n` where every number that is a multiple of 4 is replaced with "Hello", every number that is a multiple of 5 is replaced with "Wonderful" and every number that is a multiple of 7 is replaced with "World".

```
package Multiple;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            // Checking if the integer is a multiple of 4
            if ((i % 4) == 0) {
                // print
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
            // Checking if the integer is a multiple of 5.
            if ((i % 5) == 0) {
                // print
                System.out.println("Wonderful");
            }
            // Checking if the integer is a multiple of 7.
            if ((i % 7) == 0) {
                // print
                System.out.println("World");
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I put `n = 7` (for example) I expect the output "1, 2, 3, Hello,  Wonderful, 6, World", but the actual output is "1, 2, 3, Hello, 4, Wonderful, 6, World, 7".

Comment: Your title talks about removing duplicates. The body of the question makes no mention of duplicates.   Wrong choice of title?

Comment: You need to use a chain of `else if` instead of just `if`

Comment: Consider 20 which should print HelloWonderful. And in your code indeed does, so not everywhere an else. However the last println needs to know whether something was printed. Something like `if (i % 4 % 5 % 7 != 0)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen - consider the case where i is 5.  We don't want to print the number.  But ```i % 4``` is 1, so ```i % 4 % 5``` is 1, and  ```i % 4 % 5 % 7``` is 1, so we print the number.  Maybe the reverse order works (!) but I think it's clearer to code as ```i % 4 != 0 && i % 5 !=0 && i % 7 != 0```

Comment: @another-dave right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
if ((i % 4) == 0) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
} else if ((i % 5) == 0) {
    System.out.println("Wonderful");
} else if ((i % 7) == 0) {
    System.out.println("World");
} else { 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: The question seems unclear to me.  What are we supposed to do for the value 20, which is a multiple of 4 and of 5?  Your solution is to print "Hello" - i.e., being a multiple of 4 has priority.  I'd be inclined to want "Hello Wonderful", i.e., we do both multiple-of-4 and multiple-of-5. But I see it's not really clear from the question.

Comment: If he didn't specified in that case how he want to manage it, I decided to manage the case as you see above.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't intending to come across as finding fault with your answer - the two possibilities seem equally valid. Just pointing out there *are* two possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your last print statement, the unconditional

```
 System.out.println(i);
```

should only be executed if nothing has previously been printed for this particular value of `i`.

There are two ways to go about this; (1) the brute force way, preceding that statement which says "if this is not a multiple of 4 and not a multiple of 5 and not a multiple of 7", and (2) tracking whether you've printed anything.   I prefer the second approach.

I think it would be useful for you to supply the exact code, though, so I have not done so here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change
if( n!=i)
  Syso(i)

instead of end of the line of system.out.println(i);